# Conditional formatting - Borders over Multiple Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, border

I have Cells formatted like this:

[image: Twelve rows with Text in every fourth one]

If the first cell of a triplet contains the word "baz" I want them formatted so there is a border around the triplet as well as some color adjustments.

However, in the way I did this ( `=IF(A1="baz",TRUE,FALSE)` as the condidion in each of the formatting rules, copying over the format resulted with the first cell of the formula as A1, A4, A7 and A10 respectively) the Borders only go around the individual cells. I understand why it does this, but i am looking for a better way.

Comparison:

[image: Comparison]

Is there a way to make a border around multiple cells using conditional formatting?

*note: If this is a duplicate question then please link me to the solution and i will remove this one.*

Comment: Are all the other colors/rows highlighted via conditional formatting? Or is that all manually done and you just need a condition for `baz`?

Comment: @BruceWayne The formatting is done manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use this conditional formatting formula:

```
="baz"=LOOKUP("zzz",$A$1:$A1)
```

applied to range:

```
$1:$12
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this is as far as i got myself with a less clean formula (ty), but my question was rather about having a border around the highlighted block, instead of removing all of the borders in the matching triplet

Comment: @Laurenzebs ah didn't notice that. I'll take another look.